# Visual studio 2010 IDE not starting

Tags: c#, windows, ide

I have visual studio 2010 installed and working but just after re-starting my system i am not able to start development environment - 
I am getting following error -

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal,Version=10.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=
b03f5f7f11d50a3a3 or one of its dependencies.The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable (Exception FROM HRRESULT=0X80070570)

Can anyone has any clue what could be the reason ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to repair the installation via Control Panel

Comment: Looks like there is no logical reason for this problem , trying to repair now . Thanks for your suggestion.